# getting value from array to modal parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I would like to change the modal component parameter by a value from an array. But I don't know how to do it. When pass the array, it takes the code writing and not the array value.

```
componentArray: any[] = [{component: 'modal1Page'}, {component: 'modal2Page'}];

  async onClick(value: any) {
     const myModal = await this.modalController.create({ 
      component: this﻿.componentArray[0],
      cssClass: 'modalCss',
      componentProps: {
        value: value,
      }
    });
    return await myModal.present();
  }
```

It's interpreting like this: " ***component: this﻿.componentArray[0];*** " and i would like it to be interpreting like this: " ***component: modal1Page;*** "

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just missed  `.component`

```
async onClick(value: any) {
     const myModal = await this.modalController.create({ 
      component: this﻿.componentArray[0].component,
      cssClass: 'modalCss',
      componentProps: {
        value: value,
      }
    });
    return await myModal.present();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much !!